# Iphone Development : MapKit , how to add a pin without the pin stem?

Tags: iphone, mapkit

on the Mapkit,

I was wondering if it is possible to add a pin without its stem, like it only reflects the pinhead in our map, not using image btw.

Kind thanks,

Comment: Please consider voting up or tick the right answer if the answers below have helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. For that you have to use `MKAnnotationView` instead of `MKPinAnnotationView`. and do not use annotation.animatesDrop property.

Here are the sample code you can use in `viewForAnnotation`,

```
    annotation = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"try"];
    annotation.canShowCallout = YES;

    annotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];


    return annotation;
```

Hope this helps.

I see you are pretty new to stack overflow. Make sure you mark this answer or any other answer as the right answer.